# How to pass an object to a function

Tags: groovy, apache-poi

Is it possible to pass an object to a function? When executing the following it says that it cannot pass the method `createRow` to a null object

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
//import java.io.*

def getCellFromAddress(Sheet sheet, colNumber, rowNumber)
{
Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNumber);

Cell cell = row.createCell(colNumber);
return cell;
}

xlFileAddress = 'file.xlsx';
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(xlFileAddress));
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");

// Create a cell and put a value in it.
getCellFromAddress(sheet, "H9").setCellValue("test value");
```

Comment: That looks like `sheet` is null. Have you checked if it returns a value here? Maybe you need `createSheet` or something or if there are prepared sheets already, you can access them by index?

Comment: thanks for your comment. Stupid me. the name of the sheet was not correct. Now I know that I can pass an object to a function though.